how to limit requests made by webworker in angular
Currently, in my Angular project, we upload batches of files using the webworker. It turns out that the webworker can make up to six requests at a time (depending on the browser, from what I've read in other forums); however, my backend only processes one request at a time, so depending on the processing time to return the response to the frontend (despite being a promise), it ends up exceeding the waiting time.
As a stopgap, I added a 1-second timeout between requests on the frontend so the backend had enough time to process and return the response.
What I would like to know is if I can reduce these simultaneous requests from the webworker. For example, instead of 6 requests at the same time, limit it to 3?

From cursory search results I'd say the answer is "no": the maximum connections are an implementation detail, and are not specified or exposed by the user agent to be configured.

Hello, Liz.  I am working on a solution to this and other things.  I can give you something if you wait until I'm done.  I am working the weekends on synchronization primitives for web workers.  As of today, I have 3 primitives, but you need a 4th:  A semaphore.  I haven't done it.  Long story short:  Monitor the repos of WJSoftware for a new one in a month or so, possibly named @wjfe/async-workers.

Assuming you are talking about these Web Workers: no, there's nothing in their API that lets you configure the maximum concurrent connections they can make. They are an EventTarget, and AFAICT, there are issues with EventSources and concurrency, which I assume are thus related. These issues are up to the user agent to resolve. This means each user agent may solve things differently, and no specification exists that could reliably let you configure this.
However, rate limiting is not a hard problem to solve. You could use a "counting semaphore" to track how many requests you are already making, and a buffer when there's requests waiting. Assuming you use something Promise based, you can create intermediary promises that resolve once the call is taken from the buffer:
let calls = 0;
const maxCalls = 6;
const buffer = [];

function rateLimitedCall(callFactory) {
  // Are we already making `maxCalls` at this time?
  if (calls >= maxCalls) {
    // Then buffer this request and create a Promise
    // that the caller can wait on.
    let resolve, reject;
    const promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
      resolve = res;
      reject = rej;
    });
    // Store the call together with its promise handlers
    // in the buffer.
    buffer.push([callFactory, resolve, reject]);
    return promise;
  } else {
    // There's open splots, we are going to start a new call.
    calls++;
    // Create your call
    const promise = callFactory();
    // When this promise finishes, we should check if there's
    // more calls waiting in the buffer
    const handleNext = (value) => {
      // Get the next buffered item
      const [next, resolveNext, rejectNext] = buffer.shift() ?? [];
      if (next) {
        // Execute it, and resolve/reject the promise
        // that the user of the buffered item is waiting for
        next().then(resolveNext, rejectNext);
      } else {
        // Nothing next to do, so just open up our slot.
        calls--;
      }
      // Return our input as our output, as if nothing happened.
      return value;
    };

    // Return the new promised with the extra handlers ninja'ed in.
    return promise.then(handleNext, handleNext);
  }
}

Assuming you have an array batchData of 1000 parameter sets for requests to make, you can use it like this:
const batch = await Promise.all(
  batchData.map(parameters => rateLimitedCall(() => request(...parameters)))
)

The key point is that you wrap your request in a () => ... so that the actuall call that creates the promise is delayed until our buffer mechanism calls it.
Here I create an example where we create 10 calls:
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].forEach(i => {
  const myPromise = rateLimitedCall(async () => i)
  myPromise.then((i) => console.log('RESOLVED', i));
});

This will resolve the promises in order, and you can place console log in the if/else branches of rateLimitedCall to verify that after the first 6 calls the calls are placed in the buffer, and resolved later when an earlier call resolves.
PS: I use buffer.shift, which can be slow for large numbers of buffered items. If that matters, you can implement better double ended queues for the buffer.
